# What is the touch event for long press on mobile web?

Tags: javascript, touch-event, web-frontend, long-press

I am able to get the start of a long press via `touchstart` event. However, it doesn't trigger `touchend` after the long press is completed, when the right click menu appears nor when the right click menu is dismissed.

How can I detect when the long press is completed?

Comment: Maybe it's the contextmenu event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes that was it! Thank you  question solved